# Find all nodes within range of one node in unknown (tree like) data structure

Tags: data-structures, go

the other day I made a quick tool to figure out exactly what the question asked but with a fixed range, which works well just by using a stupid amount of for loops but I would like to make it work for a use definable range.

The data structure in looks like

[image: this]

Where each node can link to any other number of nodes and can all link back to itself it you follow the right path(Which tended to break my implementations).

It's just defined as

`type Node struct {
    Name string
    ID   int
}`

And you can get a list of nodes it is linked with using a method which returns a slice of Nodes which gets the information from a database with around 5,000 entries.

Initially I tried some stuff with recursion which just ended up with me having a hurt head and code that just doesn't work.  I just can't seem to get my head around this.

Thanks in advance, and if this type of data has a specific name I would love to know what it is!

Comment: This s a well-known problem in graphs. Look for `breadth search first` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search and `depth search first` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search . Both can be solved by recursion or iteration, but the recursive one is very easy to implement.

Comment: That definitely put me in the right direction and I figured it out and it runs about the same speed as my static implementation.

Answer (score 0):

My final code looked something like this

```
func rec(x Node, depth int) Node {
    s := make([]Node, 0)
    if depth == 0 {
        s = append(s, x)
    } else {
        for _, y := range x.Get() {
            s = append(s, rec(y, depth-1)...)
        }
    }
    return s
}
```

and it worked wonderfully.  Thanks a lot to [siritinga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2137314/siritinga) for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: won't this create an infinite loop if there are loops in your graph? you can add a duplicate filter if you need to make sure that doesn't happen.

Comment: Yes, usually you have an attribute "visited", set initially to false. When you visit a node, you set visited to true. This way you won't follow any loop.

Comment: You are welcome! By the way, I suppose that `rec` returns `[]Node` instead of `Node` , doesn't it?